# Save powerpoint presentation without image compression

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, powerpoint-2013

I am using the powerpoint interop library to programmatically open a powerpoint presentation, make changes to it, and then save it.

The problem is when I call the presentation.save() method, it compresses most of the images in the presentation.

Is there a way to disable this automatic compression?